# How to create a tarball that includes only part of the specific path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tar

I need to create a tarball for directory:

```
/opt/myuser/userContents/JDK-17
```

into

```
/opt/myuser/userContents/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

I would like only the JDK-17 directory to be packaged into the jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz file.

**However, for some reason, I would not be able to cd into any directory. My current directory is always /.**

The command I issued was:

```
tar -czf /opt/myuser/userContents/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt/myuser/userContents/JDK-17
```

However, the jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz file I created packages the whole directory structure

```
/opt/myuser/userContents/JDK-17
```

rather than just

```
JDK-17
```

I know it will be straightforward if I can cd into the directory /opt/myuser/userContents. However, because I cannot cd, how I can create a tarball as required?

Comment: Can you explain why `cd /opt/myuser/userContents` does not work? What happens when you try it? What is the output of `type cd`? Please don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: @Bodo I actually ran these in Jenkins script console which does not have context. If I run cd /opt/myuser/userContents the directory is only changed in the current context. The next command I issued will be in / again.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question and add all iformation there.** Why not `/opt/myuser/userContents && tar -czf /opt/myuser/userContents/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz JDK-17` as a single command? Or alternatively create a shell script and run this from Jenkins.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#directory

Comment: @Bodo Thanks. This works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Bodo's suggestion. The following command works for me:

```
tar -czf /opt/myuser/userContents/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/myuser/userContents JDK-17
```

Comment: Please improve your question anyway.